# MySQL group by hour starting with specific time

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have minute wise data in mysql table in the following format.  (Data starts from 09:15 onwards and data may not be present for some minutes.)

```
data_timestmap      data_value
------------------- ----------
2022-11-25 09:15:59 3149.00
2022-11-25 09:16:59 3150.00
2022-11-25 09:17:59 3148.70
2022-11-25 09:18:59 3143.95
2022-11-25 09:19:59 3143.15
2022-11-25 09:46:59 3144.00
2022-11-25 09:59:59 3131.20
2022-11-25 10:00:59 3136.50
2022-11-25 10:01:59 3137.95
2022-11-25 10:02:59 3139.95
2022-11-25 10:04:59 3139.90
2022-11-25 10:17:59 3132.40
2022-11-25 10:18:59 3128.30
2022-11-25 10:19:58 3130.75
2022-11-25 10:20:58 3130.00
2022-11-25 10:51:58 3124.05
2022-11-25 10:52:58 3123.75
2022-11-25 10:53:58 3121.50
2022-11-25 10:54:58 3119.05
2022-11-25 10:59:57 3120.85
2022-11-25 11:00:58 3120.95
2022-11-25 11:01:58 3121.45
2022-11-25 11:02:58 3121.35
2022-11-25 11:03:58 3119.25
2022-11-25 11:09:57 3127.05
2022-11-25 11:10:59 3125.40
2022-11-25 11:11:58 3120.85
2022-11-25 11:12:58 3121.00
2022-11-25 11:13:59 3121.15
2022-11-25 11:14:58 3119.30
2022-11-25 11:15:59 3120.35
2022-11-25 11:16:59 3120.80
```

I tried to group by hour by using this query:

```
SELECT max(data_timestamp), max(data_value), min(data_value), 
FROM data_table 
GROUP BY ( HOUR( data_timestamp ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( data_timestamp )/60  ));
```

It is grouping by 1 hour with max(data_timestamp) as 2022-11-25 09:59:59, 2022-11-25 10:59:59 etc.

But I want the grouping with max(data_timestamp) as 2022-11-25 10:15:59, 2022-11-25 11:15:59 etc.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: `.. GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2022-11-25 09:16:00', data_timestamp) ..`

Comment: um, i do curious, why did you use `floor` which will always result anything less than `1` will be rounded into `0`? if you used `ceil` things would have been different though. can you explain more on the time cutoff before a data point considered to belong the next hour group?